# Monitoring Tags in Azure and generating alerts

Tags: azure, automation, azure-monitoring

Is there a way to monitor tags maybe using Azure Monitor on resources that do not have tags or do not have the minimum tags (in this case VMs only) and either apply default tags or generate an alert? In AWS, for example cloudwatch events allows for monitoring tags instead of always calling APIs.

Comment: Pretty sure you cant do that out of the box with OMS\Azure Monitor. But you might want to look at Azure policies

Comment: I figured only Azure policy can do this. However, it would not work on previously deployed resources without tags. If I set up a policy now, it would only work on newly created resources. Edit: actually I can you can also audit tags with azure policy. I'll give that a try too. Thanks